# How do I delete an image inside a JLabel by right clicking my mouse

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'm working on an Animal Project and I want to improve the project with the MouseListener functions, but I cannot find out how to do this specific bit and I've looked everywhere. Here is my code so you get a good idea at what I'm doing.

**Main Class**

```
public class Animals {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame application = new JFrame("Animal Project");

    GUI graphicalInterface = new GUI();
    application.add(graphicalInterface);

    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.setLocation(200, 200);
    application.pack();
    application.setVisible(true);
    application.setResizable(false);
}
```

**Sub Class**

```
public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JButton animalOption = new JButton();
private JButton save = new JButton();
private JButton load = new JButton();
private JButton clear = new JButton();
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JPanel imagePanel;
private ImageIcon bear;
private ImageIcon tiger;
private ImageIcon lion;
private JLabel imageBlock1;
private JLabel imageBlock2;
private JLabel imageBlock3;
private int choice;
private int count = 1;
private JLabel currImageBlock = null;

GUI() {
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);

    //create button panel
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 230));
    buttonPanel.setOpaque(true);
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    buttonPanel.setBorder(blackline);
    imagePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    imagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    imagePanel.setOpaque(true);
    imagePanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    imagePanel.setBorder(blackline);
    imageBlock1 = new JLabel();
    imageBlock1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    imageBlock1.setOpaque(true);
    imageBlock1.setBackground(Color.white);
    imageBlock1.setBorder(blackline);
    imageBlock2 = new JLabel();
    imageBlock2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    imageBlock2.setOpaque(true);
    imageBlock2.setBackground(Color.white);
    imageBlock2.setBorder(blackline);
    imageBlock3 = new JLabel();
    imageBlock3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    imageBlock3.setOpaque(true);
    imageBlock3.setBackground(Color.white);
    imageBlock3.setBorder(blackline);

    bear = new ImageIcon("Bear.png");
    tiger = new ImageIcon("Tiger.png");
    lion = new ImageIcon("Lion.png");

    animalOption = new JButton();
    //add action listener to each button
    animalOption.addActionListener(this);
    //set button size
    animalOption.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    //set text for each button
    animalOption.setText("Animal");
    animalOption.setToolTipText("press to select your animal");
    //add buttons to gui
    buttonPanel.add(animalOption);

    save = new JButton();
    //add action listener to each button
    save.addActionListener(this);
    //set button size
    save.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    //set text for each button
    save.setText("Save");
    save.setToolTipText("press to save your selection");
    //add buttons to gui
    buttonPanel.add(save);

    load = new JButton();
    //add action listener to each button
    load.addActionListener(this);
    //set button size
    load.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    //set text for each button
    load.setText("Load");
    load.setToolTipText("press to load your selection");
    //add buttons to gui
    buttonPanel.add(load);

    clear = new JButton();
    //add action listener to each button
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    //set button size
    clear.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    //set text for each button
    clear.setText("Clear");
    clear.setToolTipText("press to clear your selection");
    //add buttons to gui
    buttonPanel.add(clear);

    this.add(buttonPanel);
    this.add(imagePanel);
    imagePanel.add(imageBlock1);
    imagePanel.add(imageBlock2);
    imagePanel.add(imageBlock3);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (count == 1) {
        currImageBlock = imageBlock1;
    } else if (count == 2) {
        currImageBlock = imageBlock2;
    } else if (count == 3) {
        currImageBlock = imageBlock3;
    } else if (count > 3 && e.getSource().equals(animalOption)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(imagePanel, "Your choices have exceeded, please press clear.");
    }

    if (e.getSource().equals(animalOption) && count < 4) {
        choice = selectAnimal();
        if (choice == 1) {
            currImageBlock.setIcon(bear);
            currImageBlock.setToolTipText("This is a bear");
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            currImageBlock.setIcon(tiger);
            currImageBlock.setToolTipText("This is a tiger");
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            currImageBlock.setIcon(lion);
            currImageBlock.setToolTipText("This is a lion");
        }
        chooseNumber();
        count++;
    }

    if (e.getSource().equals(clear)) {
        imageBlock1.setIcon(null);
        imageBlock2.setIcon(null);
        imageBlock3.setIcon(null);
        imageBlock1.revalidate();
        imageBlock2.revalidate();
        imageBlock3.revalidate();
        count = 1;
    }
}

static int selectAnimal() {

    int animal = 0;
    String theAnimal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter animal, type 1 for bear, type 2 for tiger, type 3 for lion");
    animal = Integer.parseInt(theAnimal);

    return animal;

}
```

And this is what it looks like when I run the code and after I've selected which Animal I want

[image]

I have a clear all button where if I click it, it clears all the images in inside the imageBlock Jlabel, however I want to add a feature where if I right click on the specific JLabel the image and all its contents will be deleted inside that specific JLabel. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: [How to write a mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) would be a place to start

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've just read and I'm still not completely understanding, I've just tried implementing it there but I don't know how to create an instance on the right click to trigger that very action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example code shows how a mouse listener can be used to perform an action (in this case - remove) on an image set as icon within a `JLabel`. Note a `MouseAdapter` is used in the code but a `MouseListener` interface can be implemented with similar result.

Other ways of performing this function:

- Select an image label and click a button to remove it.
- Open a context or pop-up menu with remove image menu option - when the image label is right-clicked upon.

The example code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ImageLabelAction {
    private JLabel imageBlock;
    private ImageIcon koala = new ImageIcon("koala.jpg");
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new ImageLabelAction().gui();
    }
    private void gui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Frame with Image Label");
        imageBlock = new JLabel();
        imageBlock.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        imageBlock.setOpaque(true);
        imageBlock.setBackground(Color.white);
        imageBlock.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        imageBlock.setIcon(koala);
        imageBlock.addMouseListener(new PictureRemoveListener());
        frame.add(imageBlock);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(250, 250);        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class PictureRemoveListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                imageBlock.setIcon(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dude you're a hero seriously, thank you for that example, you made it look so easy, I now completely get it, MouseEvent.BUTTON3, you have no idea how hard it was to get that info without reading pages and pages of unnecessary text. Thank you my man this is best answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could set a mouse listener to just move it way out of the frame when right clicked. Or you can make a boolean if mouse is clicked set true and only show that object if the boolean is true, so where you set the image from the file only run that code if right mouse button hasn't been clicked

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following pseudo code:

```
imageBlock1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
        // use flags to figure out if it is right mouse click
        imageBlock1.setIcon(null);
    }
});
```

Do this for imageBlock2, 3, 4 etc.

It has been a while but something along those lines could do what you are asking.